# appium driver show error in URL

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, appium

hi make script for appium selenium

```
 File file = new File("/home/prakash/ApkProjects" , "EasyBooking Sri Lanka_v2.0.31_apkpure.com.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("app" , file.getAbsolutePath());

        AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("endpoint address") , capabilities);
```

this tow line show as error in URL [image]

but i add these jars

**1.java-client-6.0.0

2.selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0**

how can i fix this issue? thz

Comment: have you imported java.net.* package?

Comment: yep _AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver1 = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>( new URL( http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub ) )_  this show http: error (not "") in url

Comment: missing http in the url? also check appium server is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to assign the driver value with the assigned capabilities and the path of app:

```
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(completeURL), capabilities);
```

here completeURL contains your appium driver URL and the capabilities has the assigned capabilities.

Comment: same error   when URL () its empty no error when enter address only its show error

Comment: `private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(completeURL), capabilities);`  in this line **URL** show in _red_